# Can an iOS app be added later to an Apple Watch only app?

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-6

Beginning with WatchOS 6 [Apple makes it possible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps) to ship Watch-only apps. While we can first ship an iOS app and later add a companion app for the Apple Watch, I'm wondering if the reverse is possible as well:

Can we ship an Apple Watch-only app, which is installed via WatchOS App Store directly on the watch and then later add an iOS app to it?

This is important to me as I don't want to put a barrier on front of this option. You may still find out after publishing your watch app that it will profit from having a companion app on the iPhone. Or you might find that your watch app will gain more publicity when its iOS companion app becomes visible in the iOS App Store as well.

Comment: Did you have success with this? Im wondering what you did regarding your bundle ID and if you had any issues.

Comment: I would expect the bundle ID to stay the same because both apps belong together. I would do as the accepted answer to this question says: Add a new target, choose iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is simply a matter of going to the project at the top level of the project navigator, then adding a new iOS target to your Apple Watch project.